# Can a 1st level Wizard communicate with a non-raven familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

The raven familiar can speak a language, but can a 1st level Wizard master speak or exchange thoughts with other kinds of familiars? Or is it necessary to wait for "Speak with master" at 5th level?

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59632/what-is-the-point-of-having-a-1st-level-familiar-if-you-cant-communicate-with-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't talk with your familiar until you gain the **Speak with master** skill, but remember that you do have an Empathic Link to it.

> Empathic Link (Su): The master has an empathic link with his familiar to a 1 mile distance. The master can communicate empathically with the familiar, but cannot see through its eyes. Because of the link's limited nature, only general emotions can be shared. The master has the same connection to an item or place that his familiar does.

So there is some limited communication possible.